# Nanosecond timing across kernel?

Tags: c, linux, unix, kernel, latency

I am planning to write some software direct to an FPGA network card, to catch incoming customised network packets.

Eventually I believe I will send the data obtained either to the kernel or to a user application. This is for a latency-critical trading research project.

What kind of nanosecond timing instruments could I use due to the accuracy required and also the fact that I am timing the duration between reception at the PCI-E network card and receivership in the kernel?

This will be on Linux, with "driver" code (I may put the user application at this level to cut latency) written in C.

Comment: The CPU's [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) comes to mind. I am not sure what hardware you have on the network side... Which card are you using?

Comment: Due to the limitations it'll probably be AdvancedIO or Napatech. Here's advancedIO: http://www.advancedio.com/markets/financial/ultra-low-latency-trading/

Comment: Impressive hardware. :-) To measure time on the FPGA you just use the Clock signal and a Register. What software/hardware will you run on the FPGA?

Comment: @Mackie, out of curiosity do you know pricing details for that hardware? what hardware on the FPGA? I presumed it was a case of writing a C-like language and flashing it to the FPGA? I used "Handle-C" on an FPGA back at university....

Comment: I would guess a few thousand USD. The traditional approach is to use a HDL like Verilog or VHDL. Measuring time is trivial in these languages. Nor sure about Handle-C... The idea of this device is to do all the critical processing on the FPGA to avoid the latency of the PCI bus. So you should have a very good idea of how to program the FPGA.

Comment: I think if i am going to keep all the processing on the card, the card will determine the timing rather than the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

On linux access to the CPU clock tick is through the [tsc](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/kernel/tsc.c) equivalent to the Windows QueryPerformanceCOunter

Comment: Hi Martin, would I be able to access this from the FPGA/Network Card if I programmed the FPGA?

Comment: This is a CPU instruction it runs in the CPU and returns the CPU counter. YOu would have to read it in a driver in the kernel and send it to the PCI card

Answer (score 1):

`clock_gettime` uses HPET if available, which is simple and as good and as reliable as you can get.

If HPET is *not* available, you have no reliable timer at that scale anyway, so unluckily the resolution of `clock_gettime` will be worse, but that's just what it is, and there's not much you can do about it.

Any other source, including tsc, is either lower resolution or unreliable or both.

Answer (score 0):

In software every thing happens on multiples of system clock. I think you can use any time measurement function that returns the number of elapsed clock ticks, `clock()` for example should give you enough accuracy.

Comment: clock() returns microseconds but has a granularity of between a few 100ms and 1s

Comment: The only reason I wasnt sure was because I read somewhere that calling functions (presumably in Java or C#) like getTimeOfDay() have a great deal of overhead. Therefore I wasnt sure what native C functions would not require massive overhead.